# Not to cache a particular page in cq5 dispatcher

Tags: caching, configuration, aem, dispatcher

I am creating webpages using Cq5/AEM.
Is there any configuration to be made , so that a particular page should not be cached in dispatcher .

Answer (score 2):

As per the [reference link](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#Specifying%20the%20Documents%20to%20Cache)

There are different ways with which this can be achieved. From configuration perspective, you can specify `deny` rule in dispatcher configuration, something like below. For understanding on globbing patterns refer [globbing patterns](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#par_title_25). The reference link explains more details about different ways.

```
/rules
  {
   /0000  { /glob "*" /type "allow" }
   /0001  { /glob "/en/news/*" /type "deny" }
   /0002  { /glob "*/private/*" /type "deny"  }   
  }
```

Comment: Thank You will try this.